# Scala map : How to add new entries

Tags: scala, immutability

I have created my scala map as :

```
val A:Map[String, String] = Map()
```

Then I am trying to add entries as :

```
val B = AttributeCodes.map { s =>

    val attributeVal:String = <someString>
    if (!attributeVal.isEmpty)
    {
      A + (s -> attributeVal)
    }
    else
      ()
  }
```

And after this part of the code, I am seeing A is still empty. And, B is of type :

```
Pattern: B: IndexedSeq[Any]
```

I need a map to add entries and the same or different map in return to be used later in the code. However, I can not use "var" for that. Any insight on this problem and how to resolve this?

Comment: `A += (s -> attributeVal)` or `A updated (s, attributeVal)`. [[source](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html)]

Comment: I tried and see this compilation error : value update is not a member of Map[String,String]
[ERROR]           A(s)=attributeVal

Comment: And for A += (s -> attributeVal) I get syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala uses immutability in many cases and encourages you to do the same.

Do not create an empty map, create a `Map[String, String]` with `.map` and `.filter`

```
val A = AttributeCodes.map { s =>
      val attributeVal:String = <someString>
      s -> attributeVal
}.toMap.filter(e => !e._1.isEmpty && !e._2.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, the default `Map` type is immutable. `<Map> + <Tuple>` creates a new map instance with the additional entry added.

There are 2 ways round this:

1. Use `scala.collection.mutable.Map` instead:

   ```scala
   val A:immutable.Map[String, String] = immutable.Map()

   AttributeCodes.forEach { s =>
     val attributeVal:String = <someString>
     if (!attributeVal.isEmpty){
       A.put(s, attributeVal)
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create in immutable map using a fold:

   ```scala
   val A: Map[String,String] = AttributeCodes.foldLeft(Map(), { m, s =>
     val attributeVal:String = <someString>
     if (!attributeVal.isEmpty){
       m + (s -> attributeVal)
     } else {
       m
     }
   }
   ```